# How to parse an ObjectId type from the url in the routes of Playframework

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework

I am using play 2.7.x with **Java** and I am trying to parse the mongodb's ObjectId from the url in the `routes` config file like this:

```
GET      /tasks/:id/view       controllers.TaskController.viewTask(id: org.bson.types.ObjectId)
```

I don't really need any mongodb features except validating the ObjectId in the url.

My `build.sbt` file is:

```
name := """bla-bla-core"""
organization := "com.bla"
maintainer := "bla@bla.com"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"


lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  ws,
  ehcache,
  filters,
  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.0.1",
)
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
Compilation error[No URL path binder found for type org.bson.types.ObjectId. Try to implement an implicit PathBindable for this type.]
```

Did anybody set up mongodb's objectId parsing from the route before in Playframework? I assumed it is quite common issue and I would find the solution easily but nothing I tried works :/

All the solutions where talking about some package called `"se.radley" %% "play-plugins-salat"` that was last maintained in 2016 :D

Answer (score 0):

Try having it as String and transform to ObjectId in controller.